# How to show the pre-checked UITableViewCells at the time of editing the form.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have one of the form in which the user is allowed to select some fields, For selected items i used `[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];` ,The logic i have used is , I have taken the emptyMutableArray and at the time of didSelectRowAtIndex delegate method i checked if the selected indexPath is present in that emptyMutableArray, If its present means the item is already selected then i remove that indexPath from that emptyMutableArray, But if that indexPath is not present in it, i add the indexPath in that emptyMutableArray. Ok after that i reloads the same tableView and at that time in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath i again have one if statement for setting the cell AccessoryType where i checks if the indexPath is present in the emptyMutableArray if its there i set the AccessoryType of cell to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark otherwise i set it to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone, 
          After that Where the problem coming is when the user will try to edit such a form then i want to show the already selected items and thats what the issue , You all will understand the problem from my code for that.

This is the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate methods code which decides which cell should have check mark

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
 cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:13];
 cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 else if (tableView==roleTableView) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [roleAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if([emptyMutableArray containsObject:indexPath]){
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

        } else {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        }
    }
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    return cell;
}
```

and this is the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of tableView from where the user decides which item should be selected or deselected.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 else if (tableView==roleTableView){

        NSLog(@"IndexPath Obj:-%@",indexPath);
        if([emptyMutableArray containsObject:indexPath]){
            [emptyMutableArray removeObject:indexPath];

            [roleMutableAry removeObject:[roleIdAry objectAtIndex:[roleAry indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[roleAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];
        }
        else {
            [emptyMutableArray addObject:indexPath];

            [roleMutableAry addObject:[roleIdAry objectAtIndex:[roleAry indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[roleAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];
        }
        NSLog(@"roleMutableAry:%@",roleMutableAry);

        if ([roleMutableAry count]==0) {
            //[roleBtn setTitle:@"Select role" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        [roleTableView reloadData];
        [self loadInvitees];
        [peoplesOfDiffRoleTableView reloadData];

    }
}
```

I know it was typical for me to express the exact problem, But once you understand the code i will explain where the problem occurring while showing the already selected (checked) items second time.

Comment: May be you should explain clearly what you actually want? what form? etc. I have read 2 times but I am unable to visualize your problem. I think you should add the object from "roleAry" or "roleIdAry" corresponding to a cell into "emptyMutableAry". After that you can easily compare cell's title value with the one in your "emptyMutableAry".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot depend upon the IndexPath for setting some properties of cell as because the cells get reused.  What I understand from your question is that you want to keep a track of the cell that has been selected and later want the table view to accordingly show the accessory type. For this you should have an array which will contain objects that will have a property as "isSelected" or anything you want. This property will help you in setting you accessory type based on its value. In your cellForRowAtIndex you need to fetch the corresponding object out from the array and check for the property "isSelected" or whatever you define and accordingly set the accessory type of the cell. I hope this will help you. Cheers!